# Why is audo clip not playing on document.getElementById().play()

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to build a drum-machine in React. When I click a button I would like the audio clip of the child to play. To do this I am passing the id the button and audio to a method when clicked, and then using document.getElementById(Id).play(). However, this does not work. Am I in the right ballpark here or totally wrong?

```
import * as React from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react@17.0.1";
import * as ReactDOM from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react-dom@17.0.1";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.playClip = this.playClip.bind(this);
  }
  
  playClip = (e) => {
    const id = event.target.id;
    document.getElementById(id).play();
  }
  
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="container" id="drum-machine">
        <h3>My drum-machine</h3>
        
        <div class="grid" id="display">
          <button className="drum-pad" id="Q" onClick={this.playClip}>Q<audio className="clip" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.min.js" id="Q" /></button>
          <button className="drum-pad" id="W" onClick={this.playClip}>W<audio className="clip" src="" id="W" /></button>
          <button className="drum-pad" id="E" onClick={this.playClip}>E<audio className="clip" src="" id="E" /></button>
          <button className="drum-pad" id="A" onClick={this.playClip}>A<audio className="clip" src="" id="A" /></button>
          <button className="drum-pad" id="S" onClick={this.playClip}>S<audio className="clip" src="" id="S" /></button>
          <button className="drum-pad" id="D" onClick={this.playClip}>D<audio className="clip" src="" id="D" /></button>
          <button className="drum-pad" id="Z" onClick={this.playClip}>Z<audio className="clip" src="" id="Z" /></button>
          <button className="drum-pad" id="X" onClick={this.playClip}>X<audio className="clip" src="" id="X" /></button>
          <button className="drum-pad" id="C" onClick={this.playClip}>C<audio className="clip" src="" id="C" /></button>
        </div>
      
      </div>
    )
  }
  
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("drum-machine"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the `play` method on the **button** instead of on the **audio** element.

(When you have invalid HTML with duplicate ids, `getElementById` will find the first match).

You could hack this with `document.getElementById(id).querySelector('audio').play();`

But it would be cleaner to make the button and everything in it a component and use a ref.

```
const AudioButton = ({letter, src}) => {
    const audioElement = useRef(null);
    const onButtonClick = () => {
        audioElement.current.play();
    }
    return (
        <button className="drum-pad" onClick={onButtonClick}>
            {letter}
            <audio className="clip" src={src} />
        </button>
    );
}
```

and then:

```
<div class="grid" id="display">
    <AudioButton letter="Q" src="q.mp3" />
    <AudioButton letter="W" src="w.mp3" />
    etc
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

I tried the 'hacking' method, and although my program was now targeting the <audio> tag rather than the <button> it was still failing to produce sound (or pass FreeCodeCamp's tests). 

I then opted for the more sophisticated method, but receive 'Uncaught ReferenceError: useRef is not defined' as an error.

Comment: @JoelPearce — See [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). You have to import it. `import React, { useRef } from 'react';`

Answer (score -1):

Your IDs should be all unique. You are calling play on button element and not a child audio element as they both have the same id. Also as you are already getting target after the click event you don't need to search it by ID again. The event will pass you the target element, and you can get its child audio element.

```
playClip = (e) => {
    const id = event.target.id;
    document.getElementById(id).play();
  }
```

this method does not work as you are passing *e* but then are using non existing in the scope *event* variable. It should be both *e*  or *event*. My version would be:

```
playClip = (e) => {
    e.target.querySelector("audio").play();
  }
```

then you don't need the ID on audio elements at all as long as each button has a child audio element.